# Pass parameters in a function along with list

Tags: groovy

I have a function with two parameters which accepts string and a list. I now need to pass a third String parameter into this function which defaults to an empty string. Heres my function :
Here is how I call the function:

```
rows("{CALL " + storedProc + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}",param1,param2,param3)
```

Here is the function

```
List<GroovyRowResult> rows(String query,java.lang.Object[] parameterMap){
    ......
}
```

Now, in the above function, the input parameters is as follows:

```
query = {CALL reportStoredProc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
parameterMap = [param1,param2,param3]
```

When I put a thrid default paramter in the function like:

```
List<GroovyRowResult> rows(String query,java.lang.Object[] parameterMap, String test=''){
    ......
}
```

if i pass "Hello" as test the string in test is taken as an elemtn in the list. So, now the parmeters will be:

```
query = {CALL reportStoredProc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
parameterMap = [param1,param2,param3,Hello]
test = ''
```

Is, there a workaround here to pass the third parameter without add it into the list? It might be a silly question but Im stuck with this for some time now.

**Note: to call stored procedure I am compelled to use rows instead of call or execute. Also, I cant use [] to pass parameterMap while calling the function.
Also, the test must be the third parameter**

Thanks,

Comment: Put your `String test='' ` before `parameterMap` and it will solve your problem.

Comment: @PrakashThete i know it will work if test was put  before parameterMap. But as i stated in the question I need it in the third.

Comment: Your method header looks right. You might be calling the function wrong. Could you show the code where you actually call the method?

Comment: Call it with `rows("the query", [p1,p2,p3], "My Last String)`